# How do i target a specific digit in a multiple-digit number

Tags: c++

So I'm making a binary->decimal program where i need to target a specific digit in the number which is inputed, so for instance if the input is 100110110, how do i target the fourth digit, in this case obviously being 1, and the fifth, sixth, ... how many ever digits there are?

Comment: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c?rq=1)

Comment: do you have the binary in a string or in an int / long

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a binary string, store the input in a string and process it using a loop

```
string num = "1001010";
int l = num.length();

for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
    // num[i] is the (i+1)th bit from left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> how many ever digits there are?

these are called bits. To find number of bits in a variable use [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator that returns number of bytes.

```
sizeof(variable) * 8
```

> how do i target the fourth digit

you can test a bit with `operator&`:

```
if (8 == (variable & 8))
    ...
```

There are already detailed answers on how to do that: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c?rq=1)

Comment: This answer does not address how to read or write individual bits, or access them as OP puts it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux why would you address something that have been done properly years ago. I added link in the comment.

Comment: If you know that this question has already been correctly answered before and have a link to that answer, why did you not vote for duplicate?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Because it asks also about number of digits. And you vote down because of what?..

Comment: can someone link me something about the basics of bits, havent read into them much; also is there any library you need to include for bits?

Comment: @TejasK Google for `Bits Manipulation in C` or something like that. This is usually covered in beginner programming books. No library is needed for that